# add a new row consisting of 2 combobox ,1 textfield and a button to panel in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

On cliking on the button the whole row should get duplicated.

Here is what I have done using normal JavaScript :

function addRow()
{
    var dataval= document.getElementById("dup").innerHTML;
    var x=document.getElementById('table').insertRow(0);
    x.innerHTML=dataval;
}

Volvo
            Saab
            Fiat
            Audi
        
    
    
        
            Volvo
            Saab
            Fiat
            Audi

I want to build this kind of example on the panel in EXTJS.
plzz help !!!
I am just a beginner of EXTJS.

Rohan,

[php Developer](http://www.rohunz.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining array of comboBox, array of textField and array of button. and you can arrange these in a row using colum model. You just neeed to call function to add new row in which you can put comboBoxes, textField and a button.